# Are 3-8 input NAND gates common?

Tags: digital-logic, design, ttl

If I have, for example, 4-8 (or more) inputs that I need to AND together (or even NAND or OR) should I look for larger input devices like the 7430 NAND or is common practice to daisy chain multiple quad 2-inputs together?

I'm reading the ZX Spectrum ULA book and a lot of the circuits seem to have up to 8 inputs going through to one OR/NOR/AND/NAND.

I didn't know if those schematic symbols were just shortcuts to represent multiple IC's or if it was/is common to use the higher input devices.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Please post a picture, or a sketch, or a link when you say "I didn't know if *those* schematic symbols [...]".  Otherwise, we don't know exactly which symbols you are referring to, and we have to guess.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the reference material with me at the time but I will see if I can find some and post...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try searching yourself at a distributor such as Digikey to get some idea of availability.

I'll take you through a step-by-step if I was looking for, say, a NOR gate with at least 4 inputs. I'll be primarily interested in 4000 series CMOS or 74HC CMOS families (usually it would not be for the same application).

First, get on the site and search for NOR gates under "gates and inverters" and select "In Stock".

[image]

Now highlight the number of inputs as shown above, and click "Apply Filters".

[image]

Then narrow it down to the logic families of interest as shown above and hit "Apply Filters".

[image]

Then drill down to reasonable packaging (assuming you're not going to buy a reel). You know what to do..

[image]

Only one page remains, now sort it by decreasing available quantity by clicking the column head, as above. The sorted column will be highlighted (grayed).

You can see that about the only choice available with the above constraints is various versions of the 74HC4002 or the 4002, and they seem to be fairly available. It's a dual 4-input gate.

You can repeat this for whatever gate you are looking for, and it takes very little time.

You can cascade gates, however you obviously lose one gate's worth of propagation time every time you go through another gate in series. If you combine two 4-input gates with a 2-input gate to get an 8-input gate, you will have two propagation delays.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer.  I probably didn't word my question very well but that's essentially what I was trying to find out.  As in, "are 4 input gates too rare to put in a circuit".  But then again, all of my circuits would be open sourced and hobby projects so high volume wouldn't be an issue but I would hate for people creating my circuits to have a hard time finding those gates.

Comment: @cbmeeks Yup. It gives you some idea of whether the parts will be around in a few years. If there is only one manufacturer left and parts are not stocked, and a wide variety of packages are not available then your open-source folks might not be able to find them in a year or three.

Answer (score 5):

There were quite a few 3-input gates made, with three circuits per package.  This meant that 12 pins would be needed (3 inputs, 1 output) x 3 and adding VCC and GND uses up all 14 pins in a 14-pin package which was very popular at the time these parts were designed 40 some years ago.  Here are the 3-input logic ICs I am aware of:

```
triple 3-input NAND 74HCT10, CD4023
triple 3-input NOR 74HCT27, CD4025
triple 3-input OR  74HCT4075, CD4075 
triple 3-input AND 74HCT11, CD4073
```

There were the same types of 4-input gates made, now with two circuits per package.  This meant that 10 pins would be needed (4 inputs, 1 output) x 2, and adding VCC and GND would leave two pins unused in a 14-pin package.  So why four inputs when there could be five?  Perhaps because 4-wide bus widths are more common.  Here are the 4-input logic ICs I am aware of:

```
dual 4-input NAND 74HCT20, CD4012
dual 4-input NOR 74HCT4002, CD4002
dual 4-input AND 74HCT21, CD4082
dual 4-input OR  CD4072
```

Note a dual 4-input OR was never released in the 7400 series family as far as I know.

Someone did come along and finally design a dual 5-input NOR gate (which made use of the two unused pins), but it was released in only two families: 74F260 and 74S60.  So apparently it has not been too popular.  There are no dual 5-input NAND, AND, or OR gates.

Only two 8-input gates have been made, as far as I know:

```
8-input NAND 74HCT30, CD4068B
8-input NOR/OR 74HC4078
```

Until the 74HC4078 was released, there were no 8-input OR or NOR gates available.  But note the 744078 is not available in the HCT family, only HC.  And it is rather hard to find, being listed but out of stock at both Digi-Key and Mouser.  The NOR/OR designation doesn't mean there are both OR and NOR gates inside the package, rather the eight inputs are fed into a NOR, and that is followed by an inverter.  So both NOR and OR outputs are available at the same time.

As before, one wonders why 8 inputs (requiring 9 pins, leaving three unused) and not 11 inputs (requiring 12 pins, leaving the remaining two for VCC and GND).  Again, all I can think of was to limit the width to match common bus widths.

The 74HC133 is a 13-input NAND and is not available in the HCT family.  Except for it, I am not aware of any 6, 7, 9 or higher input gates of any type.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer and reference to part numbers.

Comment: @cbmeeks As far as availability goes, you would be very safe choosing one of the eight chips where I listed both a 74HCTxxx part number and a CDxxx part number.

Comment: Do you have any idea if there was any chip-layout reason for leaving pins unused on things like the dual 4-input NAND package, rather than e.g. including both true and complement outputs [basically adding an extra inverter stage], using five-input gates, or perhaps using five-input gates with one input inverted?  I guess adding extra inverters might have increased power consumption slightly, but I would expect that a substantial fraction of the inverters would end up being useful.

Comment: @supercat No I am not.  As I said in my answer, I just think 4 and 8-input gates seemed more logical.  Adding the complemented outputs, using up the extra two pins would have been very useful but apparently no one though of it at the time.  I'm surprised no one has released variations on the basic types with that feature.

Comment: @tcrosley: I find it interesting that there haven't been more "commodity" chips in the 74xx-style introduced to ease some miscellaneous problems (e.g. combine two NAND and two NOR gates in a package, or three independent two-input digital mux gates, or four common-select two-input pass gates, etc.)  I've seen a few nice "clever" logic gates, but they seem to be single source.  It would seem R&D costs for such devices should be low enough that a company which designed some could benefit by licensing them for next to nothing (thus allowing them to be seen as "commodity" parts...

Comment: ...and increasing engineers' willingness to incorporate them into their designs).

Comment: Well at least we have it better than the 1960's.  The Apollo Guidance Computer, which flew to the moon, used 2,800 logic ICs -- all the same type (dual 3-input NORs).  I imagine this was for reliability.  Of course you can make any logic element from either NAND or NOR gates.  The chip family was RTL (resistor-transistor logic) and each chip cost around $15-$20 apiece (in 1962 dollars) depending on the purchase order.

Comment: @tcrosley Given your mention of 4-bit and 8-bit buses being the most prevalent, perhaps it was considered preferable to not create 5, 6, 7 or 11 input designs because the unused but functional pins when used in a 4-bit or 8-bit design would need to be explicitly pulled up or down as appropriate, in order to not leave them floating and hence sensitive to noise.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh You may be right; although pulling down to ground doesn't need a resistor, for TTL the current for a low level signal at an input is 40 times that of a high-level input. So pull-ups are preferred but they require a resistor.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few more-than-two input logic gates available. For example, the 7400 series of logic gates is outlined on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits).

For 8-input specifically, there is:
7430    8-input NAND gate
744078  8-input OR/NOR gate